# Disable, bypass or make exception for Program Compatibility Assistant (PCA) in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1-preview

My problem is irritating Program Compatibility Assistant (PCA) in Win 8.1 - not on one program has problems, but many many of them.

I found many ways for disabling it designed for Win 7 & 8 but none of them (shutting down service pcasvc, changing group policy; yes, I rebooted the PC) works. 
Any idea to hack Windows to make it accepting old programs would be appreciated.

BTW: writing own exe to replace pcalua.exe (and possibly seriously mess up system ) would be final necessity.

Answer (score -1):

ask the app developers for updates instead of trying to damaged for Windows by disabling buildin tool which prevent running incompatible programs. MS changed the GetVersion(Ex) APIs in 8.1 and this causes such error messages:

**Operating system versioning**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn302074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I know I should do this but I am not using my computer in typical way so I won't get support from devs of all apps that have problems. 
I also don't like MS saying me what will work and what won't ;)

Comment: ask the devs for updates or accept the PCA dialog.